# Error in MySQL trigger while inserting & updating same table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I am writing one trigger on top of one table.
Schema is as follow:

[Schema is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2yqH.png)

Below is the trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER after_servicestatushistory_insert;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_servicestatushistory_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON servicestatushistory FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE prevServiceTransIndex INT;
DECLARE prevUserIndex INT;
DECLARE prevServiceOptionIndex INT;
set @prevServiceTransIndex = 0;
set @prevUserIndex = 0;
set @prevServiceOptionIndex =0;
select USERINDEX into @prevUserIndex from servicestransactions where SERVICETRANSACTIONINDEX = NEW.SERVICETRANSACTIONINDEX;
select SERVICEOPTIONINDEX into @prevServiceOptionIndex from servicestransactions where SERVICETRANSACTIONINDEX = NEW.SERVICETRANSACTIONINDEX and userindex = @prevUserIndex;
select SERVICETRANSACTIONINDEX into @prevServiceTransIndex from servicestransactions where USERINDEX=@prevUserIndex and SERVICEOPTIONINDEX = @prevServiceOptionIndex ORDER BY  STARTDATE desc limit 1,1;
IF @prevServiceTransIndex <> 0 THEN
update servicestatushistory set CUSTOMDATE4 = NOW() where ServiceTransactionIndex = @prevServiceTransIndex;
END IF; 
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

It is throwing below error:

````
ERROR 1442 (HY000): **Can't update table 'servicestatushistory' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger**.```


So Is there any other way to achieve this ?
````

Comment: Please add table definition, sample data, an insert or 2 and the desired outcome as text in the question.

Comment: AFTER INSERT ON servicestatushistory - is this right all the selects in the trigger are from servicestransactions   and that makes me think the insert is on servicestransactions